# "Except for us" or "Except us"

Tags: difference

Please check the two sentences below.

1. No one calls us names **except for us**.
2. No one calls us names **except us**.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, you can use either one:

> 1a. No one calls us names **except for** us.
>   1b. No one calls us names **except** us.

In this example "us" is the list of exceptions to the set of all people ("everyone").  When you have a discrete set like this, you can use either one with the same meaning.

But sometimes you don't have a discrete set.  For example:

> 2a. It was a pleasant day, **except for** the weather.
>   2b. *It was a pleasant day, **except** the weather.

"A pleasant day" isn't a discrete set of things to which "the weather" is an exception.  As a result, you need **except for**.

---

You also use **except for** at the beginning of a sentence:

> 3a. **Except for** me, everyone got to eat cake.
>   3b. ***Except** me, everyone got to eat cake.

But you typically use **except** before a preposition phrase:

> 4a. <sup>?</sup>She likes to go for walks **except for** on rainy days.
>   4b. She likes to go for walks **except** on rainy days.

(People do say things like example 4a, but it's a lot less common.)

Comment: Can I just say "for the weather" here constitute a part？ So actually it's "except + for the weather", the same usage like "She is young for her age".

Comment: Yes, "for the weather" is a constituent (specifically, a preposition phrase).

Comment: great answer! didn't really know the difference up to today.

Comment: Where did you get this explanation? Is it of your own making or can you cite a reference? Regarding 2b's _except the weather_ being ungrammatical, I wonder why this ngram says otherwise: https://goo.gl/NenFY6

Comment: Of course the chart tells us no such thing.  *Except the weather* is perfectly fine as a string in examples like "Occluded fronts are similar to cold fronts, **except the weather isn't as violent**", which are what you're finding in Google Books (please don't call the tool "Ngram" unless you want to confuse linguists).  This comment would make a good case study in how not to use Google Books Ngram Viewer.