# "Except for" before an imperative sentence

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality, imperative-sentences

> Except for Louisa, who’s away in Berlin this weekend, we’ll all be at the party.

The first example is from Cambridge Dictionary.

> - Move all the furniture except the desk to the first floor.
> - Except for the desk, move all the furniture to the first floor.

The second and third examples are mine. Is the third example correct?

(To me, it looks that "except for" doesn't have a subject.)

Comment: Isn't the desk the subject in the third?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Well, yes :-) I don't understand how to describe my "feelings" properly. So you mean that 3rd example is actually correct?

Comment: Yes. Why do you think it might not be?

Comment: Except for Frisky, all of my cats are black. Except for my mother, all my family are vegetarians. Except for Joe, all my friends have cars.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks a lot :-) I will re-write it as the answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An imperative sentence is a command, a demand, an instruction, or a request, etc. The subject is whoever is being told to do something.  The subject is usually omitted, though:

- Finish your homework.
- You finish your homework.

They are equivalent in a sense, and the subject in both is "You". But the second one is a bit awkward, and has some different meanings depending on how you say it.  Often when it is included, it expresses irritation; it sounds like scolding (and often uses an exclamation point)  It is also worth mentioning that the implied subject, "You", might refer to a single listener or a group being spoken to, equivalent to "Everyone" or "All of you".  There are many slang equivalents, too.

But to answer your question - "except" and "except for" are interchangeable. (edit: almost - see comments) You could even say "Excepting for", but this is archaic.  Not archaic, but lengthy, you could even say

- With the exception of the desk, move all the furniture...

The fact that it is imperative doesn't change how "except" and "except for" work.  And to be clear, both of your statements are grammatically correct.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm not really sure that "except" and "except for" are interchangeable: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18001/except-for-us-or-except-us It seems there are some nuances there.

Comment: Ah, yes - nice day except for the weather is a very good example.  Thanks.

Comment: I would say the older usage of "for" in the sense of "because of" is at play in this whole issue.  A little mission-creep, if you will.